# Problem with passing command from C++ program to terminal

Tags: c++, linux

When I run this command in terminal, it works perfectly

`df | awk '/ \/$/{print "HDD "$5}'`

Output:

`HDD 52%`

I want to build a C++ program to pass this command line to the terminal:

Code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    system("df | awk '/ \/$/{print \"HDD \"$5}'");
}
```

But when I run it, I got an error:

```
awk: line 1: runaway regular expression /{print "HD ...
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to escape the backslashes. `"df | awk '/ \\/$/{print \\"HDD \\"$5}'"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with bellow :

```
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    system("df | awk '/ \\/$/{print \"HDD \"$5}'");
}
```

If you want to use of backslash in c++ string, you should add `\\` instead of `\`.